# Como ordenar indices de un objeto según sus valores

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

Tengo un objeto con diferentes valores tal que así:

```
var cnsm = {
    '1': getValor("Q28_1_1"),
    '2': getValor("Q28_1_2"),
    '3': getValor("Q28_1_3"),
    '4': getValor("Q28_1_4"),
    '5': getValor("Q28_1_5"),
};
```

Los valores de cada uno dependen de factores externos, en cada situación la función getValor devuelve diferentes valores numéricos y pueden coincidir entre ellos. Estoy tratando de obtener una lista ordenada, pero lo que me interesa no es el valor en sí sino su indice. ¿Alguien puede iluminarme? Estoy bloqueado. Mil gracias!

Comment: el objeto que tienes,puede cambiar las key por una palabra igual para todos? si es asi puedes usar array sort

Comment: que devuelve getValor(), por momentos tu pregunta falta detalles , donde esta el ejemplo ,que intentastes?

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres una lista ordenada, usa un array, no un objeto:

```
const cnsm= [];
cndm.push(getValor("Q28_1_1"));
cndm.push(getValor("Q28_1_2"));
cndm.push(getValor("Q28_1_3"));
cndm.push(getValor("Q28_1_4"));
```

Y podrás usar el índice para recorrer la lista:

```
for (let i=0;i<cndm.length;i++) {
  console.log(cndm[indice]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo ideal, si fuese posible, sería utilizar un array, sino habría que hacer algo como esto:

```js
const getValor = (parametro) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 10;
}


var cnsm = {
  '1': getValor("Q28_1_1"),
  '2': getValor("Q28_1_2"),
  '3': getValor("Q28_1_3"),
  '4': getValor("Q28_1_4"),
  '5': getValor("Q28_1_5"),
};

const ordenado = Object.keys(cnsm).map(e => {
    let obj = {};
    obj[e] = cnsm[e];
    return obj;
  }).sort((a, b) => Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0]);


console.log(ordenado);
```

Primero se transforma el objeto en un array de objetos, y luego lo ordenamos con `sort()`. Si quieres que el resultado vuelva a ser un objeto, hay que usar `forEach()` o `reduce()` pero cuidado que **los objetos no tienen orden garantizado**, de manera que no tiene mucho sentido ordenar un objeto.

Si quieres una lista ordenada (Array) únicamente de las propiedades del objeto, puedes agregar al final `.map(e => Object.keys(e)[0]);`

Si tuvieses un array de objetos, sería mucho mas corto ordenarlo:

```js
const getValor = (valor) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 10;
}

var cnsm = [
  {'1': getValor("Q28_1_1")},
  {'2': getValor("Q28_1_2")},
  {'3': getValor("Q28_1_3")},
  {'4': getValor("Q28_1_4")},
  {'5': getValor("Q28_1_5")},
];

const ordenado = cnsm.sort((a, b) => Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0]);

console.log(ordenado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obtén la lista numerada de los indices con `Object.keys(cnsm)`, esto te dará una lista de todos los índices tipo

```
console.log(cnsm) = [1,2,3,4,5]; // los índices de tu objeto
```

Una tengas ésta lista puedes utilizar el método `Array.sort()` para ordenarlo y así poder finalmente ordenar tu objeto.

[Documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)